# Advice on how to search and return strings

Tags: string, mongodb, search, indexing

Forgive me, this will be my first every post to SO, so do let me know how I can improve.

I am currently looking for advice on a problem I am facing.  I have a list of one billion unique strings of text.  These text strings also have a list of tags associated with them to indicate the content of the string.

Example:

```
StringText: The cat ate on Sunday
AnimalCode: c001
ActionCode: a001
TimeCode:   d001
```

where

```
c001 = The cat
a001= ate
d001 = on Sunday
```

I have loaded all of the strings and their codes as individual documents in an instance of MongoDB

At present, I am trying to devise a method by which I can enter a string and search against the database to return the match.  My problem is that the search is taking far to long to return results.

I have created an index on the StringText field, but am guessing that it is too large to hold in memory.

Each string has an equal probability of being searched for so I can't reliably predict which strings have a higher probability of being searched for and pull them out into another collection.

Currently, I am running the DB off a single box with 16GB of RAM and a 4TB HDD.

Does anybody have any advice on how I might accomplish my task more efficiently? Is Mongo the right technology or are there others more adept at doing this kind of search and return?

My goal (forgive me if foolish) would be to try and return a result within 2 seconds or less.

I am very new to this whole arena so any and all advice would be welcome.

Thanks much to all in advance for the help and time.

Sincerely,
Zinga

Comment: If you're searching on the basis of StringText, what's the purpose of Animal, Action and Time codes?

Comment: Hi galactocalypse...the codes are used to link the phrase to other phrases  of similar meaning in another DB.   i.e c001 = the cat and also links to another code for  "the feline" etc. etc. The goal is to map a string to its codified values.

Comment: Is the structure of all input sentences supposed to be the same?

Comment: The input will always require at least an animal and an action.  Day will be optional.  So if the input was "The cat ate" results would return "The cat ate on Sunday", "The cat ate on Monday", "The cat ate on Tuesday" etc. etc.  (The cat is quite hungry it seems).  Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it did. Have you considered preprocessing the input string to find the relevant AnimalCode, ActionCode and optionally the TimeCode to make the impending search directly dependent on the indexed codes instead of tedious text search?

Comment: It had not crossed my mind. In another example, we would receive a string like "The mouse walked on Thursday" .  Are you suggesting I segment out the string to identify the components "The mouse" = m001, "walked" = a002, "on Thursday" = d005 instead of doing a full string comparison? Thanks for the great discussion by the way!

Comment: Yes, indeed. Processing one string will definitely take much less time than searching through a billion records. I'm sure the animal and/or action records are pretty small, so preprocessing shouldn't be much of a hassle. And searching a billion records based on those indexes shouldn't take much long either. As a plus, you could shard your collection based on animal and/or action codes.

Comment: I've never undertaken such a task before, but am excited to try.  Any chance you could point me towards some resources on how to accomplish the preprocessing of the string?  No worries if not. This has been awesome.

Comment: Sure. Added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you could preprocess the input string to find the associated Animal and Action codes and search for StringText based on the indexed codes, which is much faster than text search.

You can't totally avoid text search, so reduce it to the Animal and/or Action collection by tokenizing the input string. See how you can use [map/reduce](http://jeff.jke.net/2010/12/07/mapreduce) techniques just for queries of this sort.

In your case, if you know that the first word or two will always contain the name of the animal, just use those one or two words to search for the relevant animal. Searching through the Animal/Actions collection shouldn't take long. In case it does, you can keep a periodically updating list of most common animals/actions (based on their frequency) and search against that to make it faster. This is also discussed in the articles on the linked page.

If even after that your search against StringText is slow, you could shard the StringText collection by Animal/Action codes. The [official doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) should suffice for this and there's not much that's involved in the setup so you might try this anyway. **The basic ideology everywhere is to restrict your target space as much as possible.** Searching through a billion records for every query is plain overkill. Cache where you can, preprocess where you can, show guesses while you run a slow query.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome galactocalypse.  I'm off on a grand adventure.  Thanks for the map. When I get enough rep, I will come back here and +1 you.

Comment: Glad to help! You'll have loads of queries as you go. Good luck.